# find the change from uppercase to lowercase in a sentence and separate the text (print)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a problem, i need to separate a text between uppercase to lowercase sentences and print them.

Sample:
WE, THE PEOPLE OF INDIA, having solemnly resolved to constitute India into a SOVEREIGN, SOCIALIST, SECULAR, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC and to secure to all its citizens

Result:
WE, THE PEOPLE OF INDIA,
having solemnly resolved to constitute India into a 
SOVEREIGN, SOCIALIST, SECULAR, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC 
and to secure to all its citizens

I have this:

```
i=0
s='WE, THE PEOPLE OF INDIA, having solemnly resolved, to constitute India into a SOVEREIGN, SOCIALIST, SECULAR, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC and to secure to all its citizens'
t= ''
while i < len(s):
    if not(s[i].isalpha())==True:
       i += 1
       continue
    if s[i].isupper()==s[i+1].islower():
        i += 1
        t = t+','
        print(s[i])
        break
    t=t+s[i]
    #print(t)
    i += 1
print(t)
print(i)
```

but, this is my result:

**WETHEPEOPLEOFINDIAhavin,**

I don't understand why it doesn't stop at the 'h'.

Please, help me!.

Comment: Your "sample" and "result" are exactly the same.  Why not just set `t = s`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, can you provide an example of what your expected output should be? Your sample and result show exactly the same thing. In the mean time, please check out this help topic, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, it offers some great info on how to ask questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to group the words up by whether they're uppercase or (partially) lowercase, `itertools.groupby` might be an easier way:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(
...     ' '.join(w) for _, w in itertools.groupby(
...         s.split(' '),
...         lambda w: any(c.islower() for c in w)
...     )
... ))
WE, THE PEOPLE OF INDIA,
having solemnly resolved, to constitute India into a
SOVEREIGN, SOCIALIST, SECULAR, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC
and to secure to all its citizens
```

Your code stops at `"g "` because `"g".isupper()` and `" ".islower()` are both `False`, which satisfies the equality check that breaks your loop.  It doesn't stop at `" h"` because `" ".isupper()` is `False` but `"h".islower()` is `True`.

For your code to work the way you want it to work, skipping the non-alphabetic characters in the loop isn't sufficient because they still exist in `s`.  Splitting the string and operating on the resulting list (as I did in my code above) makes it a lot easier, as does categorizing the words as complete units (which is what the `groupby` does with the `any` function) rather than trying to detect the boundaries between them.